# Tracing images to grease pencil : how does the scale param work?

Tags: python, grease-pencil

I'm scripting something that is exporting grease pencil frames to PNGs, process them in another software, and now i try to import them back, trace them to grease pencil again, and move them at the exact same position as initial frames.

The main issue for me is about the scale parameter of the ops.gpencil.trace_image() operator.

```
bpy.ops.gpencil.trace_image(target=src_ob, thickness=10, resolution=10, scale=0.515, sample=0, threshold=0.8, turnpolicy='MINORITY')
```

It doesn't seem to be influenced by the scale of the image at object level, nor his resolution. with trials and errors 0.515 seemed to work for one frame but unfortunately it's not working for other image ratio.

Any thought ?